# Error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.2

I am using CakePHP Version 2.2.3. Having imported my database into PHPMyAdmin, I went on to create my MVC sing CakePHP's bake console. This all went well, I declared my relationships etc...

The problem occurs on creating the last 'view' (All the models/controllers were created without error).

The full error is: Error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'website.connections' doesn't exist

Where as I can confirm it does exist, both table,controller,model and view!

I'm exceptionally confused, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

**Update**

On the 'Members' model, on commenting out the 'Has Many' code relating to Connections, the error then appears for the next relationship below it. The relationship code is:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Connections' => array(
        'className' => 'Connections',
        'foreignKey' => 'Member_ID',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    ),
    'Recommendations' => array(
        'className' => 'Recommendations',
        'foreignKey' => 'Member_Being_Recommended_ID',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    ),
    'Groups' => array(
        'className' => 'Groups',
        'foreignKey' => 'Member_ID',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
);
```

So once the 'connections' relationship is commented out, the error then moves onto Recommendations, the one below it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per CakePHP's [conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html) all model names should be singular not plural, so that's the first thing you should fix.

Comment: It appears having singular named models solved the problem! Thank you ADmad, enjoy the 50 bounty points ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to sound repetitive but you are getting this error because the table (website.connections) cannot be found in the database your app is connected to.

Here are some tips to help you troubleshoot this problem:

1. Verify, using PHPMyAdmin, that the table (connections) exists and that it is in the database (website).  If you are using shared hosting, your database name may have a prefix that you cannot control (i.e. yourusername_website).
2. Make sure you are connected to the correct database ([config docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#database-configuration)).
3. If you have a model named Connection that doesn't use a table make sure you add `public $useTable = false;` to it.

Comment: Hi Lawrence, Thank you for your reply. I can confirm 'Connections' is in  the database, as it shows up when i'm trying to make a Model,Controller or View. It's definitely in PHPMyAdmin, along side the other 6 tables and I've even made a Model,Controller and View for it! The other view I need to create 'Members' has a one to many relationship with it, but surely that shouldn't matter?